# How do I know which AVX C functions are available on different processor models

Tags: c, optimization, x86, avx, cpuid

Basically the title. For example, I am trying to run instructions like:

`_mm256_load_pd`, `_mm256_add_pd`, `_mm256_stream_pd` and the 128 bits version on the processor: Intel Xeon, E5630, 2.53 GHz, IBM HS22. But I am getting `Illegal instruction` any idea for a site where I could see which functions are available for this processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `/proc/cpuinfo` if you're on an OS that has one.

Or use clang or gcc `-march=native` - they will refuse to compile any intrinsics your CPU doesn't support.  (Unlike MSVC or ICC, which will let you use intrinsics without telling it that the target machine supports them.)

---

To look it up by CPU model, google the model, e.g. `Xeon, E5630` ->
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/47924/intel-xeon-processor-e5630-12m-cache-2-53-ghz-5-86-gt-s-intel-qpi.html

- Instruction Set Extensions: Intel® SSE4.2

So no AVX at all, because it's a Westmere-EP microarchitecture from 2010 (before Sandybridge.)

For more detail CPUs, you can also check http://instlatx64.atw.hu/ and check the CPUID dump for that model (or one of the same microarchitecture), if you can find one.  e.g. [a screenshot of Aida64 CPUID](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel/GenuineIntel00206F2_Eagleton_CPUID.png) running on a Westmere-EX, and [instruction latency/throughput benchmark output](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel/GenuineIntel00206F2_Eagleton_InstLatX86.txt), with info at the top of the text file including decoded CPUID info showing which ISA extensions it has.  Also [raw CPUID dumps](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel/GenuineIntel00206F2_Eagleton_CPUID.txt) which you can cross-reference with the CPUID feature-bit required (https://sandpile.org/x86/cpuid.htm) by any extension you're interested in (like `cmpxchg16b` or FSGSBASE that Intel's ark pages won't mention.).

---

related: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/ tells you what ISA extension is required by the corresponding asm instruction for each intrinsic.

Comment: On macOS: `sysctl machdep.cpu.features machdep.cpu.leaf7_features`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! Can you show me a way to check for that in the C code? To run that code only if it has AVX512 or AVX2? Maybe some Macro IFs

Comment: @C.Cristi: That's a separate question.  You can of course detect at build-time with `#if __AVX__`, if you want people to compile your code with `-march=native` on their own machines.  If you want to do runtime dispatching (e.g. setting function pointers), you need to pick large-enough functions to be worth branching for (e.g. making them not inlineable), but you can use GCC's `ifunc` stuff, or roll your own with `__builtin_cpu_supports("avx")` or whatever in GNU C.  Search google / Stack Overflow for more.

Comment: @PeterCordes So, for AVX2 we have `#if __AVX__`, and for AVX512 we have `#if __AVX512__`? and compiling ofcourse with `-march=native`, and should be good to go, right?

Comment: @C.Cristi: yes, if you're not using MSVC, this all works very nicely using `-march=native`.  MSVC is designed around a model of building one binary that you distribute, and has no equivalent option to build a binary that targets the host specifically.  So it sounds like for your purposes, you want `gcc` or `clang` `-O3 -march=native`, possibly with -ffast-math, etc. etc. (definitely `-fno-math-errno`).

Comment: For the specific macros, google is your friend: [How to detect SSE/SSE2/AVX/AVX2/AVX-512/AVX-128-FMA/KCVI availability at compile-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28939652)  was the first hit for `gcc macro avx avx512`